# complementary colors in Julia (RGB versus Lab colorspace)

Tags: colors, julia, color-space, lab-color-space, color-conversion

Complementary (light) colors are defined as : "light colors such that, when added, mix to white (or neutral)".

Thus, in RGB:, let c(R,G,B) be a light color; then  cC(Rc,Gc,Bc) are complements iff R+Rc=G+Gc=B+Bc
this means that there is a segment of complementary colors defined by two points:
(1-R,1-G,1-B) and (m-R,m-G,m-B) where m=maximum(R,G,B).

If two colors are complementary, they should remain complementary in any color space. Shouldn't they? Thus if the Julia conversion of c(R,G,B) in Lab is c(L,a,b), converting cC(Rc,Rc,Gc) in Lab (in Julia) should give c(L,-a,-b). In general, it does not.

I have tried to convert several complementary pairs from RGB to Lab using the Julia function convert(Lab,c) but the result does not produce pairs of symmetrical values. How come? Is is a question of white point? If yes, which one to use and how to introduce it in the conversion function?

Comment: Hi, I've looked at the code converting L-a-b<-->RGB and it is quite non-linear in a way that wouldn't make the RGB complements become simple L-a-b colors. But, assuming this is not part of some critical image processing path, complementation can be done in a 3-step process `toRGB->complement->backToLab`. If you want a really-fast method of doing so, then it is more involved.

Comment: In addition, the complementation method described gives for example: `RGB(0.8,0.8,0.8)` is complement to `RGB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`, which will not preserve `L` value in Lab space.

Comment: Note: there are also many wrong way to do it. Luckily you well define your definition of complementary colours, but some colour wheels (so conversion of HSV) use s very different definition (so not "colorimeter" definition). Check that blue and yellow should be on opposite side (no purple, no orange: the best blue, and the best yellow). And for pedantry: RGB and Lab are not colour spaces, but colour models. A realization of then is a colour space (but so one must define colorimetry of primaries).

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the issue is probably more related to the  "color model" used. Nevertheless, under some "common working hypothesis" they should agree on the pairs of complementary colors they produce. Under the hypothesis that Red, Green and Blue are three color channels that we can tune (as in the colorimetry experiment), there should be one combination of these channels that produce a neutral color that would also produce a symmetrical pair in Lab, i.e. c=(L,a,b) and cC=(L,-a,-b). I can't find some.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, colors are tricky.
After playing around with complementary color definitions, I think your best bet is to define complementary colors in HSV space. In code this can be as follows:

```
using Colors

function complement_hsv(c)
    hsvc = HSV(c);
    if hsvc.h >= 180
        return typeof(c)(hsvc.h - 180, hsvc.s, hsvc.v)
    else
        return typeof(c)(hsvc.h + 180, hsvc.s, hsvc.v)
    end
end
```

This gives the added bonus (not true in OP method) of:

```
complement_hsv(complement_hsv(c)) == c
```

And in Lab space, the L stays roughly the same, and the a-b roughly reverse sign.

UPDATE:

If the desired complementary colors are needed to have the simple Lab property mentioned, this can be defined explicitly:

```
function complement_lab(c)
    labc = Lab(c);
    return typeof(c)(labc.L, -labc.a, -labc.b)
end
```

Comment: This complementary function defined in HSV is not compatible with Lab complements, i.e., two complements have same L and opposite a and b. Indeed, you already set the constraint of a similar value v, which does not translate in a similar L.

Comment: In the answer I wrote _roughly the same_ L which is not exactly the same. You can also define complements in Lab space directly, and get `comp(Lab(L,a,b)) == Lab(L, -a, -b)`.

Comment: Ok, but then the complementary relationship has a definition which depends on the considered color space (as they do not agree). How come if color complements are defined in colorimetry as "adding to neutral", assuming one can agree on some neutral. After all, I would rather take RGB(1-r,1-g,1-b)  as complement of RGB(r,g,b) or equivalently HSL(h+180,s,1-l)  as complement of HSL(h,s,l). But still the complement pair do not remain complement in Lab.

Comment: The short answer is "As usual, colors are tricky.". A longer one, is that CIE-LAB space is calibrated perceptually and makes color "addition" harder. RGB is good for color addition. So if the complementary colors are used for addition on a monitor, an RGB definition is better. If they are used for contrast in a chart, then CIE-LAB might be better. And of course, by the definition, a neutral color is the goal, but which neutral color? More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_color_spaces_and_their_uses and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_colors .

Comment: Another comment, the XYZ space might be better than RGB space for adding colors (RGB more tuned to monitor pixel color addition, and not to eye rod/cone neuron activations, so "line" in RGB might not look like a line in neuron activations).